# python pandas: create multiple empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create multiple empty pandas dataframes in the following way:

`dfnames = ['df0', 'df1', 'df2']
x = pd.Dataframes for x in dfnames`

The above mentionned line returns error syntax.
What would be the correct way to create the dataframes?

Comment: probably `df = [ pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(3) ]` and then you have list with `df[0]`, `df[1]`, `df[2]`

Comment: To obtain a `dict` use - `{x:pd.DataFrame() for x in dfnames}`. Note the extra-parenthesis  when calling an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the constructor pd.Dataframe must be called like a function, so followed by parentheses (). Now you are refering to the *module* pd.dataframes (also note the final 's').
2. the for x-construction you're using creates a sequence. In this form you can't assign it to the variable x. Instead, enclose everything right of the equal sign '=' in () or []
3. it's usually not a good idea to use the same variable x both at the left hand side and at the right hand side of the assignment, although it won't give you a language error (but possibly much confusion!).
4. to connect the names in fdnames to the dataframes, use e.g. a dict:

   dataFrames = {(name, pd.DataFrame()) for name in dfnames}

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create variables that contain empty DataFrames, this will do what you need:

```
dfnames = ['df0', 'df1', 'df2']

for x in dfnames: exec(x + ' = pd.DataFrame()')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have many data frames within a single variable name, here you are trying to save all empty data frames in `x`. Plus, you are using wrong attribute name, it is `pd.DataFrame` and not `pd.Dataframes`.

I did this and it worked-

`dfnames = ['df0', 'df1', 'df2']
x = [pd.DataFrame for x in dfnames]`