# How do I set dataframe names from a list of names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of pdb codes:

```
proteins = ['1h1p', '1h1s', '1pmn', '1q41', '1u4d_a', '1u4d_b', '1unl', '2br1']
```

I want to initialise an empty dataframe for each protein and name it after its code.

so I end up with 8 empty dataframes named:

```
dataframes = [1h1p, 1h1s, 1pmn, 1q41, 1u4d_a, 1u4d_b, 1unl, 2br1]
```

How do I do this?

Notes:

I've shown the dataframes as a list of dataframes, but I don't have to have them as a list I was just doing it for simplicity.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not entirely following - dataframes don't really have names. Columns can have names, and rows can have names, but the dataframe as a whole doesn't have a name. Can you clarify the goal here?

Comment: you can use this solution from the another question
[python pandas: create multiple empty dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361151/python-pandas-create-multiple-empty-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

proteins = ['1h1p', '1h1s', '1pmn', '1q41', '1u4d_a', '1u4d_b', '1unl', '2br1']
data = {k:[] for k in proteins}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```